# Excel - getting location of a cell

Tags: excel, lookup, minimum

I need to find the location of a specific cell in terms of its columns and rows. (C4 .. etc)

In the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evDD9.jpg

I need to check for the lowest price in a row and display its column name. so, I would need to display, in some other cell, Brand A in the case of me looking for the lowest price in the row "Jacket."

I have tried many combinations, mostly using OFFSET(). I was thinking to get the cell location of the minimum value in a range --> ADDRESS OF min(array) --> and then OFFSET() that cell one less than the number of rows it is from the top --> -(ROW()+1).

Its works fine if I explicitely give the location of the minimum cell in the range I am looking.

Answer (score 2):

In `E2` enter `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,MATCH(MIN($B2:$D2),$B2:$D2,0))`

[image: Sample]

You can then drag down this formula for other rows.